# scrapy : How to get all the paragraphs which comes after a heading?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to extract all the <p> tag text which has a heading.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<h2>My Second Heading</h2>
<p>My Second paragraph.</p>

<h3>My Third Heading</h3>
<a> There might be something else in middle </a>
<p>My Third paragraph.</p>

<p>My fourth paragraph.</p>
<p>My fifth paragraph.</p>
<p>My sixth paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to extract all the <p> tag text which comes after heading like this and ignore the oneswhich doesn't have a heading.

```
["My first paragraph", "My second paragraph", "My third paragraph"]
```

Comment: If you want to avoid the one without heading then precise the path pattern with headers.

Comment: A specific solution to your html would be `response.css(":not(p) + p::text")`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
response.xpath("//*[starts-with(name(), 'h')]/following-sibling::p[1]/text()").getall()
```

will return:

```
['My first paragraph.', 'My Second paragraph.', 'My Third paragraph.']
```